# Installing a python script as a windows service or hidden

Tags: python, windows, service, scripting, executable

I wrote a script with a bunch of modules to convert txt files to pdfs. There's a watchdog module which checks a certain folder for newly created txts, python siphons the data into a latex template which is being compiled into a pdf.

I created my abomination in PyCharm and if I start the script within PyCharm, it works flawlessly. I compiled it as exe via 'pyinstaller --onefile' and it works flawlessly.

However, I need to run it as a windows service or at least without the window existing in the task bar because... reasons. I tried:

- installing it as service via non-sucking service manager
- starting it as hidden programme via a vbs script, powershell script and nircmd

and nothing helped. I'm at a loss here, there's no interaction whatsoever with the programme so it should work, also scripts are enabled on the machine and the process is visible in the task manager. I somehow suspect that it has problems calling other python scripts while it's a service or hidden programme but it doesn't seem to be logical and I have no means to verify anything whatsoever that I'm aware of.

My last idea is to somehow let it exist as a task bar tray thingy but that would be more than a shabby solution for this whole ordeal. Could anyone help me out here? Thanks

Comment: PyInstaller should have an option to create a GUI app that doesn't have a console window, which may be all you need. You can also run a task in the background services sessions by enabling it to run whether the user is logged on or not, but non-local UNC paths and mapped network drives may not function in that case for various reasons.

Comment: To create a Windows service you need to implement the skeletal framework of a service to interact with the Services Controller using the service API. PyWin32 comes with simple demos.